# What object is a sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline that applies a ColumnTransformer actually fitting on when fit(X, Y) is called on it

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, pipeline

I am trying to get an idea of the inner workings of a scikit learn `Pipeline`.

Consider the below data set and pipeline construction.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age' : [30, 40, 37],
    'City': ['Amsterdam', 'Berlin', 'Copenhagen']
    })

OHE = OneHotEncoder()

ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('One-hot', OHE, ['City'])])

ppln = Pipeline(steps=[('preprocessor', ct),
                       ('estimator', <some_estimator>())
                       ])
```

The next step is then a fit of sorts:

```
model =  ppln.fit(data)
```

To the best of my understanding, the above is a series of steps taken that ends in `<some_estimator>.fit(???)`.

> My question is: what will the `???` actually be (or how can I determine what it will be).

I am unsure about this because I don't exactly know how the `'preprocessor'` interacts with the data. On its own, `ct.transform(data)` returns a matrix like object. In this case that would be

```
[[1,0,0],
 [0,1,0],
 [0,0,1]]
```

I am guessing that something will happen that eventually makes it so that:

```
??? =
[['Alice'  , 30, 1, 0, 0],
 ['Bob'    , 40, 0, 1, 0],
 ['Charlie', 37, 0, 0, 1]]
```

I would like to do better than guessing and know for sure what happens and gain a more complete view of what is happening under water when using a `Pipeline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is the `remainder` parameter of `ColumnTransformer`.

By default, `ColumnTransformer` drop all unprocessing data:

> By default, only the specified columns in `transformers` are transformed and combined in the output, and the non-specified columns are dropped. (default of `'drop'`).

So when you don't specify `remainder`, you have only the OHE of City column:

```
# Name, Age, City  -->  ColumnTransformer  -->  OHE(City)
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('One-hot', OHE, ['City'])])
ct.fit_transform(data)

# Output
array([[1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1.]])
```

Using `remainder='passthrough'` give you:

```
# Name, Age, City  --> ColumnTransformer  -->  OHE(City), Name, Age
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers = [('One-hot', OHE, ['City'])],
                       remainder='passthrough')
ct.fit_transform(data)

# Output
array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'Alice', 30],
       [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 'Bob', 40],
       [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 'Charlie', 37]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly then, that in eiter case `ppln.fit(data)` will be the same/equivalent to `<some_estimator>.fit(#Output)`, where `#Output` is the result of `ct.fit_transform(data)`?

Comment: Exactly, you got it. Each operation has the previous operation as input and the output is the input of the next operation and so on.